# Dynamic range condensed into one line of code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out the cleanest way to create a dynamic range and this, I think, is close to what I want it to do but I am not sure how to make it correct. Any thoughts?

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim RNG As Range
With Sheets("Open Jobs Report") 'Change to your sheet
Set RNG = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim RNG As Range
Set RNG = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

Because you were using `.` in front of some of the range objects I assume it is in a With Block like this:

```
Sub foooooii()
Dim RNG As Range
With Sheets("Sheet3") 'Change to your sheet
    Set RNG = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
End With
Debug.Print RNG.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an "Invalid or unqualified reference error on the .rows.count portion of the code.

Comment: @TonyP my guess is that you do not have it in a With Block, see edit.

Comment: @ScottCraner you could avoid "A1" and shorten it a little to "Set RNG = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))".  Sorry I can't edit it properly not being by any PC

Comment: @user3598756 You need the "A1" as the first cell of the range.  OP is looking for a range that starts with A1 and ends with the last row and last column used.  So the first "A1" is the start with the rest being the last cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner: wouldn't it be the same to have bottom-left and upper-right as range corners being the former in column A and the latter in row 1? I'm actually not by any PC to test it so I'm just "imagining" it

Comment: `.Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)` returns one cell not two.  It finds the row based on the last used cell in column A and the Column based on the last cell used in row 1.  Those two number are used in the first `.Cells()` to return the lower right of the range with "A1" being the upper left. @user3598756

Comment: @ScottCraner but that is not my code...mine is "Set RNG = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))".

Comment: @user3598756 yup, I get so into upper left to lower right I forget that you can do lower left to upper right.  Good call.  When you get to a computer offer that as an answer.  Let me know so I can up vote it.

Answer (score 3):

building on Scott's solution and just to shorten it a little:

```
Set RNG = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
```